# Working with Windows COM Objects with Nodejs/Electron

Tags: c#, node.js, .net, com

I am building a desktop application in Electronjs (runs on nodejs runtime) 
Trying to replicate the following c#, .NET code in Electron/Node 
`Type comType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(<Prog_ID>);` 
`Object comObj = Activator.CreateInstance(comType);` 
`comType.InvokeMember(<method for Prog_ID>, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, comObj, <params for method>);` 

In a nutshell this code gets a COM Object from ProgID and invokes a method on it 
I cannot find any way of doing this after much research, any help would be appreciated

Comment: C# has interop service that simplify usage of COM server from C# code. If you can't find such service in nodejs you may try to invoke COM object as regular C code (I see that nodejs can invoke native C++ calls https://medium.com/@koistya/how-to-call-c-c-code-from-node-js-86a773033892). And invoke COM server as following C client does: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/example--the-open-dialog-box

Comment: @VladNovakovsky Thank you for your suggestion Vlad. I am looking into interop with C++ like you suggested. Any other solutions which can be built exclusively as a node/electron solution